# How can I let a caller specify the underlying implementation to use in my class without them having a reference to the actual instance? (Java)

Tags: java, class, types, parameters, instance

As an example, let's say I'm making my own `Collection<E>` implementing class which uses an underlying `List<E>` for storage of elements. How can I let the user/caller specify which kind of underlying List to use without them ever having a reference to it? Having them provide an instance of the list through a constructor parameter would leave them with a reference to it and able to modify it. Having them pass a `Class<List<E>>` object would mean I have to make an instance from that (with `Class.newInstance()` or `Constructor.newInstance()` where the constructor parameter types I choose may not exist) which seems to be generally not ideal and unpredictable. And I don't think I can depend on `Object.clone()`.

But I don't necessarily need to create the instance myself (as commonly asked with instantiating generic types), I just need to ensure that the client/caller doesn't have a reference to it or otherwise can't access/modify it.

Comment: Are you on Java 8?  Java 8 seems to resolve this by letting the user pass in a `Supplier` of the specified type, e.g. `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`.

Comment: Why should it matter to the user/caller what underlying implementation your API uses? If it is required create different methods each with a different implementation. The purpose of interfaces is to ensure that the user does not have to know the underlying implementation.

Comment: @anacron Well specifically in my case, I'm making a Server class which takes an Executor as a constructor parameter, so the client/caller can specify how the Server's threads should be ran.

Comment: In that case, have an `enum` that acts as a input parameter which can be used to determine how  your threads will run.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes that's a great idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what arguments are required for the constructor of the specified class, then the client can pass through to the constructor: `(Class<List<E>>, String arg1, int arg2)`, and if you don't, just pass `(Class<List<E>>, Object... args)` where `args` is all of the needed arguments for the constructor. If they enter something invalid, it will immediately throw an exception.